# Margin around FixedDocument in DocumentViewer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer, documentviewer, fixeddocument

I am displaying a FixedDocument in a DocumentViewer, and by default the ScrollViewer shows the document with no margin above the top or below the bottom of the document.

What I'd like is to change the style of the DocumentViewer so that the scrollbars stretch along the whole edge of the DocumentViewer and this is a margin above the top and below the bottom of the document, but if the top and/or bottom of the document cannot be seen, the document stretches to the top and/or bottom edge of the DocumentViewer, respectively. (If I had the "reputation," I could post of picture showing what I am trying to achieve.)

The problem is that the ScrollViewer uses a ScrollContentPresenter to display the FixedDocument, and you can't pad the content in a ScrollContentPresenter (or at least I haven't found out how).

Using the following code, I modified the style of the ScrollViewer in the DocumentViewer's style, and I got it to look right, but for some reason, it doesn't enable the vertical scrollbar until you click on the document, and the horizontal scrollbar never enables:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ContentPresenter  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="0,50,0,50"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

There is normally a ScrollContentPresenter where I placed a ScrollViewer containing a ContentPresenter with a margin.  It is a messy solution, so I was hoping someone would know of a better solution.

If I were working with any control other than a FixedDocument, I could just define a margin around the object being displayed in the ScrollViewer, but for whatever reason, you can't define a margin around a FixedDocument, and defining a margin around a PageContent control does nothing.